# Pandas: Create dataframe from data and column order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

what i'm asking must be something very easy, but i honestly can't see it.... :(

I have an array, lets say

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], 
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [10,11,12]]
```

and i want to put it in a dataframe.
I do `df = pd.Dataframe(data, columns={'col1', 'col2', 'col3'})`

aiming for:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
10   11   12
```

but i am getting:

```
col3 col1 col2
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
10   11   12
```

**(notice the discrepancy between column names and data)**

I know i can re-arrange the column names order in the dataframe creation, but i'm trying to understand how it works.

Am i doing something wrong, or it's normal behaviour? (why though?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are are using a `{set}` of columns, which is NOT an ordered collection (neither are dictionaries).
Try with a `(tuple)`, o simply a `[list]`

```
df = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Comment: As i expected, it was something obvious! thanks to both Susensio & @mihai-alexandru-ionut

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a `tuple` or `list` as value for `columns` property.

In your example you're using a `set` of columns which is an unordered collection.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```